# getting specific array values from $_post

Tags: php

I have gotten `$_POST` values into array using this code

```
session_start();    
    foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value){
     $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
     echo $_SESSION['post'][$key]."<br/>";
    }
```

what I want to do is get a specific value

```
<input name="Fax" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" />
```

into the value of the textfield
this is where I got the form value from

```
<table>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Hotel</strong></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Hotel Name :</td><td class="left"><input name="organization" type="text" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Re-enter<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Hotel Name :</td><td class="left"><input name="re_organization" type="text" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Telephone :</td><td><input name="telephone" type="text" id="TelephoneID" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Fax :</td><td><input name="Fax" type="text" id="FaxID" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address :</td><td><input name="Address" type="text" id="AddressID" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Hotel motto :</td><td><input name="HotelMotto" type="text" id="HotelMottoID" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Note :</td><td><textarea name="Note" cols="30" rows="4" id="NoteID"></textarea></td></tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Account Administrator</strong></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Full Name :</td><td><input name="fullname" type="text" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email :</td><td><input name="email" type="text" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>Only company email can be use.<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo etc are not allowed.</td></tr>
        </table>
```

please I need help to get the value thanks in advance

Comment: Try `echo $_SESSION['post']['email'];` because you assigned it in your `foreach()` loop like that

Comment: Try to use some sort of debugger.  You should be able to inspect exactly what `$_SESSION['post']` is, this should give you a good idea of how to access the information you are looking for.

Comment: Really, you can skip the whole `foreach` loop. Since you're just assigning all key/value pairs, you can directly assign the entire `$_POST` with something like `$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;`

Comment: thanks all, i try echo $_SESSION['post']['email']; as suggested by user2191572 and it works as i wanted. thanks once again to all the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

here is a usefull trick to view the content of your arrays and get the exact index you want :

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION, true)."</pre>";
```

change `$_SESSION` with what ever array you like and you will see the exact index of the value you need 
and for your case i don't see why you are using `$_SESSION` you can directly use `$_POST` and get what ever you want